# Picker in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

i use a UIPickerView in my root view of UINavigationController . And i used one button, when i pressed it, pass the data(shows in picker) to the next level view of navigation controller.  How should i do this? Thank you!

And can you tell me the right way to manage data or share data among multi-viewControllers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the UINavigationController is the delegate of the UIPickerView. And save the data when scroll the picker in this method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;{  ...NSString * passedString = [myArray objectAtIndex:row];...}
```

After that when the button was pressed, pass the "passedString" into next viewController.